# Is there any known pre-twentieth century history of the tomb of Sidi Rezegh?

Tags: islam, north-africa, arab, islamic-history, libya

Is there any known pre-twentieth century history of the tomb of Sidi Rezegh?

[image]

A variant spelling is [Sidi Rizq from سيدي رزق at 31.8287°N, 24.1345°E](https://mapcarta.com/12509548) in [Al Butnan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butnan_District) province, Libya [near](https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B049'43.3%22N+24%C2%B008'04.2%22E/) Tobruk and Al Adm.

The place is famous for the [battles around it in 1941](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crusader#Sidi_Rezegh).

Comment: Google Scholar says no, at least not with that spelling.

Comment: Quite likely there are/have been other ways to spell it in English.

Comment: Variant spelling is Sidi Rizq from سيدي رزق at 31.8287°N, 24.1345°E. Curiously not even satellite imagery of that shrine is available at meaningful resolutions.

Comment: @LangLangC: I have it as 31°50'17"N   24°7'12"E (cannot remember source), and there is a building at that location (in Bing maps).

Comment: Do we know anything about it that is from the 20th century, that could lead to earlier references?