# Who was the Moslem saint Sidi Rezegh?

Tags: islamic-history, libya

Who was the Moslem saint *Sidi Rezegh* whose tomb is located in Cyrenaica, Libya, where an important battle was fought in 1941 between the British Eighth Army and the German Afrika Korps? I've tried Google searches but have had no luck.

Comment: Related question [Is there any known pre-twentieth century history of the tomb of Sidi Rezegh?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/53973/16951).

Comment: What is the significance of the important battle fought in 1941 in relation with this saint?

Comment: Pretty much the only references to this site are from the descriptions of the ww2 tank battle. Do a search limited to before 1939 you will not find much.

Comment: In what language are you searching?